# Hooking to all control's click events using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, events, controls

Currently I am calling a function in code behind once someone clicks on a button (using button's event) and using following ajax :

```
$('.toggleBtn').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "page.aspx/function",
                        data: "{'id': '" + id + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: false,

                        success: function (msg) {
```

Is it possible in jquery to hook to all of the controls events in current page and run only one $.ajax.

Say I have four controls, two textboxes and two comboboxes and want to update database accordingly. if i want to run the above I need to hook to their click events one by one and run separate function in code behind, which will not be ideal.

In another words want to populate my object once the user selects/inputs the control value.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: give class to all 4 inputs same i.e toggleBtn

Comment: @Dnyan but how would i know which control was filled

Comment: I would need clarification of: click any of 4 buttons to perform same action OR click a button, and use it to perform action on 4 different element groups OR perform the update when any of the four elements content changes - or do you mean something else?  It might also help to show some markup as rendered on the page.

Comment: @sam1 by using $(this) in function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're asking how to fire the same code for the click event of a group of elements, but wish to pass the ID of the clicked element as a parameter in the data.  If so, this will do it for all elements with the class `className`...

```
$('.className').click(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "page.aspx/function",
        data: "{'id': '" + this.id + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            ...
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think that would be good based on id i can populate my object...is it possible to run a none static method on ajax..as i cannot access my controls in code behind

Comment: Any values that are on the client that you need to access in the ajax call *must* be passed via `data` (or querystring, but post data is obviously preferable).  It's not relevant whether the server-side function is static or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this logic:

```
var request = 0; //global flag

$('.toggleBtn').click(function(e) {
    if (!request) {
      $.ajax({
         ..
         success: function(){
           request = 1; //update the flag
         }
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: can you explain more please, why the flag?

Comment: Wasn't me that downvoted, but I guess it's because he's not asking for it to only occur once.  He's asking how to do it for a group of elements.  You've focused on the word "once", but that's not relevant.  He means "after".

Comment: Just to keep track if the request has been made or not